# vba change event multiple targets

Tags: excel, vba

firstly apologise for the long post, I'm struggling to create a change event on VBA where a comment is created over multiple ranges. I've got the below code to work over one range, but when I try and expand it to another range, either an error occurs or it simply doesn't read the code. any help would be appreciated.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim Author, EmployeeName, SiteName, ShiftTimes, PayRate As String
Dim DateEntered As Date
Dim intRow As Integer
Dim cmt As Comment
Dim lBreak As Long

If Intersect(Target, Range("C4:AG19")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
intRow = Target.Row
Author = Application.UserName
EmployeeName = Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(Range("$B$4:$B$19"), Target.Row)
SiteName = Range("B2").Value
ShiftTimes = Application.VLookup(Target.Value, Range("AI10:AJ13"), 2, False)
SitePayRate = format((Range("AJ7").Value), "£#,##0.00") & " p/h"
DateEntered = Now()

With Target
    .ClearComments
    .AddComment Author & Chr(10) _
    & EmployeeName & Chr(10) _
    & SiteName & Chr(10) _
    & ShiftTimes & Chr(10) _
    & PayRate & Chr(10) _
    & DateEntered
    .Comment.Shape.TextFrame.AutoSize = True
    .Comment.Visible = False
End With

Set cmt = Target.Comment
If cmt Is Nothing Then
    Exit Sub
End If

'find the line break which is Chr(10)
lBreak = InStr(1, cmt.Text, Chr(10))

'format username in red and bold
With cmt.Shape.TextFrame
    .Characters.Font.Bold = False
    .Characters(1, lBreak).Font.ColorIndex = 1
    .Characters(1, lBreak).Font.Bold = True
    .Characters(lBreak + 1, Len(cmt.Text)).Font.ColorIndex = 1
End With
End Sub
```

What I'm hoping to achieve is when the target range is (C32:AG40) it calls the following information from a data table

```
If Intersect(Target, Range("C32:AG40")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
intRow = Target.Row
Author = Application.UserName
EmployeeName = Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(Range("$B$32:$B$40"), Target.Row)
SiteName = Range("B30").Value
ShiftTimes = Application.VLookup(Target.Value, Range("AI38:AJ41"), 2, False)
SitePayRate = format((Range("AJ35").Value), "£#,##0.00") & " p/h"
DateEntered = Now()
```

I hope that I've explained myself clearly and once again any help is appreciated.

Comment: try looking at `if ...... elseif........else......end if` or even `select.....case`  ELSE is the word you'll need to research on.

Answer (score 0):

I propose that you avoid the "if intersect ... then exit sub"

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    '...
    If Not (Intersect(Target, Range("C4:AG19")) Is Nothing) Then
        '...
        Debug.Print "Range C4:AG19"

    ElseIf Not (Intersect(Target, Range("C32:AG40")) Is Nothing) Then
        '...
        Debug.Print "Range C32:AG40"
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: I'm still relatively new to VBA only started using it about 6 weeks ago, I've yet to come across debug.print

Comment: debug.print in the lines above only shows the text "Range C4:AG19" in the interactive window (Press Ctrl G in VBE) when you click in the relevant range of the worksheet => so you have a confirmation that the macro is started!

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim Author, EmployeeName, SiteName, ShiftTimes, PayRate As String
    Dim DateEntered As Date
    Dim intRow As Integer
    Dim cmt As Comment
    Dim lBreak As Long

    Dim rngIndex As Range, rngSitName As Range, rngTime As Range
    Dim rngRate As Range
    Dim Rng1 As Range, Rng2 As Range

    Set Rng1 = Range("C4:AG19")
    Set Rng2 = Range("C32:AG40")

    If Intersect(Target, Union(Rng1, Rng2)) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

    If Not Intersect(Target, Rng1) Is Nothing Then
        Set rngIndex = Range("AI10:AJ13")
        Set rngSitName = Range("B2")
        Set rngTime = Range("AI10:AJ13")
        Set rngRate = Range("AJ7").Value
    ElseIf Not Intersect(Target, Rng2) Is Nothing Then
        Set rngIndex = Range("AI38:AJ41")
        Set rngSitName = Range("B30")
        Set rngTime = Range("AI10:AJ13")
        Set rngRate = Range("AJ35").Value
    End If

    intRow = Target.Row
    Author = Application.UserName
    EmployeeName = Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(rngIndex, Target.Row)
    SiteName = rngSitName
    ShiftTimes = Application.VLookup(Target.Value, rngTime, 2, False)
    SitePayRate = Format(rngRate, "￡#,##0.00") & " p/h"
    DateEntered = Now()

    With Target
        .ClearComments
        .AddComment Author & Chr(10) _
        & EmployeeName & Chr(10) _
        & SiteName & Chr(10) _
        & ShiftTimes & Chr(10) _
        & PayRate & Chr(10) _
        & DateEntered
        .Comment.Shape.TextFrame.AutoSize = True
        .Comment.Visible = False
    End With

    Set cmt = Target.Comment
    If cmt Is Nothing Then
        Exit Sub
    End If

    'find the line break which is Chr(10)
    lBreak = InStr(1, cmt.Text, Chr(10))

    'format username in red and bold
    With cmt.Shape.TextFrame
        .Characters.Font.Bold = False
        .Characters(1, lBreak).Font.ColorIndex = 1
        .Characters(1, lBreak).Font.Bold = True
        .Characters(lBreak + 1, Len(cmt.Text)).Font.ColorIndex = 1
    End With
End Sub
```